# iPhone/iTunes backup books from iBooks

Tags: iphone, itunes, books

I have some books in iBooks that were opened from third-party apps, so they are not on my mac. I would like to save them in iTunes and don't find a way to do it.

For example there are some apps, that allow you to copy music, photos or videos from iPhone/iPad, but i found none that could do books.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not heard of any apps that allow you to copy iPhone > Mac / PC, but I vaguely remember mine just copying them over anyway.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4227 suggests that they will be copied over automatically.

Comment: They will be copied indeed, thanks for the idea :-) Or if no sync was on (was my case) - "Transfer purchases" function worked perfectly.